# Angular 8 - How to dynamically style body tag based on which component user is on? ::ng-deep is being overwritten when view changes

Tags: css, angular, sass

So I have two components, both of them use ::ng-deep to modify background color of the body tag

In the About Us component, the SCSS file has:

```
::ng-deep body {
 background-color: red;
}
```

And in the Contact Us component, the SCSS file has:

```
::ng-deep body {
background-color: blue;
}
```

However, if i move to the About Us Page then go to the Contact Us Page, the following is shown in inspect

background-color: blue is overwritten by backrgound-color: red

However, it should be the otherway around since the Contact Us page should have a background-color of blue.

The inverse also leads to the same problem - bg color red is overwritten by bg color blue if i go from the Contact Us page to the About Us page.

When on the page and refreshing the browser, the problem resolves but this is not good enough for users.

I have found another SO question where the answer was to use :host but when i do this, the rule does not apply at all, it does not get recognised in the inspector.

Comment: Seriously? No one knows?